# Packages are not recognized

Tags: php, laravel, amazon-ec2, getstream-io

My environment is Laravel 7.0 (PHP7.2) and Linux 18.04.4 and
I'm trying to install `composer install get-stream/stream-chat`. It works and it gets installed and I find it in Vendor folder, however, while I'm trying to use it, I get the following error.

> Class `GetStream\StreamChat\Client` not found

Any idea?

Comment: could you please add the code of the file where you are importing that class?

Answer (score 0):

Your autoload script is maybe outdated.

For installing new dependency with composer you should use :

```
composer require get-stream/stream-chat
```

Then update autoloader if it's not already working with :

```
composer dump-autoload
```

Check https://getcomposer.org/doc/01-basic-usage.md#installing-dependencies